# Decryption in DocuSign Power form

Tags: docusignapi, docusignapextoolkit

I am opening the DocuSign power form from my salesforce org. When we open the form we pass few fields values along with power from URL (In encryption mode). I would like to know how to decrypt the values in DocuSign power form.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for the slow reply. Please be sure to always include the `docusignapi` tag with your questions. (We didn't see your question because of that issue.)

### Answer

If you want to know the values that were entered by the signer into a DocuSign powerform, then you have a couple of choices:

1. Use the eSignature REST API to retrieve the values from the envelopes. Try the [EnvelopeRecipients:list](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/enveloperecipients/list/) API method and include the query parameter `include_tabs=true`. You'll first need to get a list of the envelopes that were created because of your PowerForm.
2. Use the Connect web hook feature to receive notifications (which include the tab data) on your server.

If you have another question, please open a new question here on StackOverflow with the tag `docusignapi` Thank you.